# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library mongodb.so Symbol not found

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb php driver on MACOS, XAMPP and PHP 7.1.11 by command line `sudo pecl install mongodb` then run `php -v` and got errors

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_ce_countable
  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_ce_countable
  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Please help !

Comment: I'm getting same issue with a few of the extensions on macbook (xdebug, mongodb, redis, xhprof). all the extensions were installed using `pecl`. Trying to find out a solution and I'll update it here if something is found. Or did you find a solution already as the original issue was reported by you long time ago?

Comment: the one that helped to resolve my issue for xdebug is in this [answer from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/977257/unable-to-install-xdebug-undefined-symbol-zend-post-startup-cb). download the file from xdebug, compile it, copy it over to extension directory and then enable it in php.ini or config file.